# Net::RawIP fill source mac-address wrongly (Ubuntu)

Tags: perl, network-programming

I'm trying send udp IP packet via [Net::RawIP module](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::RawIP), and then listen to tcpdump and when i check the source mac-address in the packet i find it not matching my device mac-address. I'm using ubuntu. I tried with 2 ubuntu devices but give same results (Wrong source mac address). Mac-address seems to be filled by something but not the right value. From diffrent devices it's filled with same source mac-address (wrong). What can cause this? How can we fix it to discover right value?

Code example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Net::RawIP;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $ip_dst   = $ARGV[0];
my $port_dst = $ARGV[1];

my $payload  = "TestingMac";

my $packet = new Net::RawIP({udp => {}});

$packet->set({
            ip => {
                    saddr => 0,
                    daddr => $ip_dst
                },
            udp => {
                     source => 50,
                     dest   => $port_dst,
                     data   => $payload
                }
});

$packet->send;
```

Comment: You've provided absolutely no information about your problem. What makes you think it's wrong? What MAC address do you see? What network interfaces are on your machine?

Comment: Hi ikegami, it's like the real mac-address: `00:50:56:b6:5e:17` but when packet received it's: `c0:bf:c0:89:6a:09`, i tried with different devices i installed ubuntu on my laptop and tested and same when recieve packet i find the source: `c0:bf:c0:89:6a:09`. Tested on ubuntu/debian and same issue. I'm not sure if this module have something wrong so it fill them wrongly or what, i need help regarding this. you can try with simple code i posted to confirm this issue.

Comment: Wait, you're running tcpdump on the receiver? Is the received on the same LAN as the sender? If so, that's your issue. Are you aware that MAC addresses are only used when sending information over a LAN? If you're getting stuff from a router, you'll see the router's MAC address.

Comment: IP packets don't have MAC addresses, so no, the module has nothing to do with it. It could be selecting a different interface thatn you are expecting, but that's it.

Comment: I'm running a tcpdump on the receiver just i capature them as .pcap then check on wireshark and see that the source mac is wrong. I don't run tcpdump at the sender. Internet interface: Ethernet 01. I'm not sure so if not the module who filling the source mac?

Comment: It's not LAN. If you tried to send packet to any ip, it should include your right mac-address if i understand. In this case it include a wrong mac, i don't know much about this. Can you explain me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply because the source MAC address you see with tcpdump is the one of the last router, just before the receiver. Not the one of the sending host: **the receiving host is not on the same local network than the sender**, so the IP packet that contains the UDP payload is routed. So the sender MAC address is lost just after the first router. And the one received is the one of the last router.

Note that you could even have no MAC address at all, using another layer 2 interconnect than wired Ethernet or Wi-Fi (think of PPP, some VPN, ...).

MAC addresses are only used by the local link layer. Not by the network layer.

Comment: I don't get you well, but i tried another software send a packet and i listen to it. It's same mac, so problem seems not in the module but as you explained.